# i can't switch between auto mode and manual mode in mobile operators if i use this adb shell command

Tags: adb

I'm new here and I've tried to bring up the mobile operators menu using an adb shell command:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings\$MobileNetworkActivity
```

the problem is when i use this command, I can't switch between auto mode and manual mode, the switch doesn't change state. Any advice?

Comment: The posted command only opens the mobile network settings page (if it exists in your Android version). It does not switch anything.

Comment: Is there a command to let me switch the state?